# Brake shoe looks good?

Tags: brakes, rim-brake

I am attaching an image of my cycle's brakeshoe. Is it worn and need to be replaced or did I get ripped off? [image]

Comment: Also can't gauge from the photo how hard it is.  An old oxidised pad has poor braking performance.

Comment: The bike shop did the right thing

Answer (score 8):

Reading between your lines, I suspect you are wondering if a bike shop replaced the brake pad when it was not needed.

Its hard to be sure from that angle, while it appears to have a little life left its certainly not unreasonable to have replaced it. Replacing now is a lot better than leaving you (the customer) to run it down and destroy a wheel rim or worse.

When looking at the work done by the shop, you have to consider their liability and reputation if they did not replace it. There is also the inconvenience to the customer if they have to return to the shop in a few months for a minor job. Because of all this shops have to take a conservative approach to these kinds of decisions, and often customers can be left feeling the work may not have been needed just yet.

In future, the best was to avoid these concerns is have a conversation with the shop when you drop the bike off. Be clear what your budget is, and expectations for parts being replaced. Ask them to call you if there is any doubt.